# why this code can't reverse an array properly

Tags: c++

I have written this c++ code to reverse a array. But it is giving wrong output. Why ??

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i,a,arr[n];
    cin>>n;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(i = n-1;i>-1;i--){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: "*It is giving wrong output.*"  What was your input and expected output? What was the actual output? These are both essential parts of a [MCVE].

Comment: In `int n,i,a,arr[n];` What is the value of `n` that you are using for the array?

Comment: The size of an array is fixed once it's created. What do you think `n` equals to when you create `arr[n]`? Not to mention that variable-length arrays (with size not known at compile-time) are not in the standard C++, and you should be using a `std::vector` instead. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior. Don't count on any specific behavior.

The problem is the definition of `arr`.

It suffers from two problems.

1. Variable length arrays (VLAs) are not standard C++. They are supported by some compilers as an extension.
2. In that line, `n` is not initialized to a value before it is used. By assigning a value to `n` in `cin >> n`, the size of the array does not automatically change.

Use `std::vector<int>` for `arr` and your code should have predictable behavior.

```
int main(){
    int n,i,a;
    cin>>n;

    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(i = n-1;i>-1;i--){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

**PS**

Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for details.

Answer (score -1):

It is not working because when you write `int n, arr[n]`, at that time `n` hasn't been assigned a value.
Put `cin>>n` before `int arr[n]` and it will work correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756962/12335228 was quicker.
Edit2: As the comment suggests, my assumption that n would be zero initialized is indeed wrong.

Oh? Wrong output you say? It works for me, even tho it shouldnt.
While the logic is correct, you are well into undefined-behaviour land here:

You are declaring n and then declare arr[n] without assigning n an actual value. That means n has its default value, in the case of int 0. So your array has a capacity of 0.

C++ let's you write into that anyway, since you as the programmer are responsible for your memory. Just think of the [] operator in this case as syntactic sugar for (*arr+i), meaning the address of your array + i

Comment: "*That means n has its default value, in the case of int 0*" - that's incorrect. `n` has indeterminate value, not 0.